# Equivalent of Akka ByteString in Scala standard API

Tags: scala, akka

Is anyone aware of a standard API equivalent to Akka's ByteString: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.5/index.html#akka.util.ByteString

This very convenient class has no dependency on any other Akka code, and it saddens me to have to import the whole Akka jar just to use it.

I found this fairly old discussion mentioning adding it to the standard API, but I don't know what happened to this project: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/ZFcjGpZswRc/0tCIdXvpGBAJ

Does anyone know of an equivalent piece of code in the standard API? Or in a very lightweight library?

Comment: could you not simply include the ByteString.scala file in your project? https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.5/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/util/ByteString.scala

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I've decided to do for now, but 1) what if later I add a dependency on Akka either in my project or a project using my library? Will it confuse the compiler to see the same source file twice? 2) I still would like to know why the project of integrating this class in the standard API seems to have been canceled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [scodec-bits](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-bits). It provides two types, `BitVector` and `ByteVector` ([API docs](http://scodec.github.io/scodec-bits/latest/api/#scodec.bits.ByteVector)), supporting fast appends, take, drop, random access, etc. The library has zero dependencies. We split it out of scodec precisely because we thought it might of general use outside of [scodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec), where it's used heavily.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'll have a look at it. I especially use all the convenient `putLong`/`getLong`/`putInt`/`getInt`/... methods of `ByteString` and `ByteIterator`. I don't see anything like that in scodec but that should be fairly easy to add.

Comment: There's actually a `toInt`, `toLong`, and (coming soon) `sliceToInt` and `sliceToLong` functions. And there's `ByteVector.{fromLong,fromInt}` for the other direction.

Comment: Missed it. Thanks, that will help a lot.